# GitLab Python Clone Everything with Structure

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

I want to clone all of the projects in my GitLab environment. There are a number of groups and subgroups with their own projects. I'd like to clone the projects while maintaining the structure of the groups locally. For example:

```
Group1
  Subgroup1
     Project1
Group2
  Project1
Group3
  Subgroup1
     Project1
  Subgroup2
     Project1
     Project2
```

So if I run `cd Group3/Subgroup2/Project2` locally I would be in that respective projects code.

My code does some of the work but it breaks on subgroups:

```
import os
from git import Repo

GITLAB_TOKEN = os.getenv('GITLAB_TOKEN')

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url='https://gitlab.example.priv', private_token=GITLAB_TOKEN)

all_groups = gl.groups.list(all=True,top_level_only=True)
count=0
for group in all_groups:
    os.chdir('/Users/ken/repos')
    print("---------------- {} ----------------".format(group.full_path))
    if not os.path.exists(group.full_path):
        print("\tCreating directory for group " + group.full_path)
        os.makedirs(group.full_path)
    os.chdir(group.full_path)
    print("Cloning projects for group " + group.full_path)
    for project in group.projects.list(all=True):
        if not os.path.exists(project.path):
            Repo.clone_from(project.ssh_url_to_repo, project.path)
    print("Creating directories for subgroups")
    subgroups = group.subgroups.list()
    for subgroup in subgroups:
        if not os.path.exists(subgroup.full_path):
            os.makedirs(subgroup.full_path)
        os.chdir(subgroup.full_path)
        print("Cloning projects for subgroup " + subgroup.full_path)
        group = gl.groups.get(subgroup.id, lazy=True)
        for project in group.projects.list(all=True):
            Repo.clone_from(project.ssh_url_to_repo, project.path)
        os.chdir('..')
```

How can I iterate over groups and subgroups to clone all of the projects while maintaining the folder structure locally?

Comment: I ended up calling the projects directly and using their respective namespaces to create the pathToFolder. So rather than cd'ing in and out just create the absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up calling the projects directly and using their respective namespaces to create the pathToFolder. So rather than cd'ing in and out just create the absolute paths.

```
import os
import gitlab
from git import Repo

GITLAB_TOKEN = os.getenv('GITLAB_TOKEN')

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url='https://gitlab.example.priv', private_token=GITLAB_TOKEN)

gitBasePathRelative = "repos/"
gitBasePathRelativeAbsolut = os.path.expanduser("~/" + gitBasePathRelative)
os.makedirs(gitBasePathRelativeAbsolut,exist_ok=True)

for p in gl.projects.list(all=True):
    print("Cloning project " + p.name)
    pathToFolder = p.namespace['name'] + "/" + p.name
    if not os.path.exists(pathToFolder):
        print("\tCreating directory for project " + pathToFolder)
        os.makedirs(pathToFolder)
        Repo.clone_from(p.ssh_url_to_repo, pathToFolder)
```